# Error when uploading image to PHP scripted website

Tags: php, image-uploading, ini

I recently purchased a PHP script for my website. The software is working very well except when I try to upload images or videos (built in function).  After I upload an image using the website script, the result is "broken image" icon in place of the picture.  When you try to click on the image, the resulting link is:

**http ://www..com/thumbnail.php?pic=C:*Upload Source    Directory* \07172364.largeThumb.b.jpg&w=100&sq=Y&b=Y**

After doing some research, I found some articles that state the php.ini needs to dictate how the php script handles image uploads.  Upon looking at my php.ini file, the only line is:

`session.save_path = "/home/<directory>/public_html/tmp"`

`session.use_only_cookies = on`

I cannot find any information on what lines of coding need to be in my php.ini file in order to handle file uploads.

My questions are:

1) Am I looking in the right direction for solving this problem?

2) Is there a standard script that should be included in my php.ini in order to handle file uploads.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was that my webhost did not have my account setup correctly to upload images.  Once I contacted my webhost, the setting was corrected and my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Given this is video and not images, when you say both should be supported, perhaps it's a filesize issue. In that case you're in the right spot (php.ini) and looking to increase the upload size to a value greater than your intended video size:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 20M
```

Comment: I ensured that my php.ini file has this information in it; however, the problem is still the same.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can't offer much without more detail, such as the error message